# first character of string in shell not working

Tags: string, shell

So I have some code where I'm trying to only do the while loop if the first character of a string isn't or is a certain character.

```
   while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a myArray
   do

    like=${myArray[0]}
    position=${myArray[1]}

    while [ ${like:0:1}=="E" ]
    file=$like."Rput"
    echo "$file"
```

So when I echo the file, the file name is ##file.output which is a file that I do not want at all. In the sense, I want it to completely skip it.

Could someone tell me what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if `while` is replaced with an `if-then` statement:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a myArray
do 
    like=${myArray[0]}
    position=${myArray[1]}

    if [ "${like:0:1}" == "E" ]
    then
        file=$like."Rput"
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

Note also that spaces are important.  The following tests first character of `like` for equality with `E`:

```
[ "${like:0:1}" == "E" ]
```

But, the following does something unrelated:

```
[ "${like:0:1}"=="E" ]
```

Since the equal sign here is not separated by spaces, `"${like:0:1}"=="E"` is interpreted simply as a single string.  Tests of a single string return true if the string is nonempty and false if it is empty.  Since `${like:0:1}"=="E"` is always non-empty, it will always return true.

Comment: I love Stack Overflow. Thank you so much!

Comment: So I have this code now: 

if [ "${gene:0:1}" == "E" ]
        then
        file=$gene."Rput"
                for something in $directories
                do
                  if [ -f $something/$gene."output.bed.output" ];
                        then
                  Rscript Rscript2.R /path/to/directory/$file                         fi
done
fi
In the Rscript, I do file.info(args[1])$size, and it returns NA. I want to basically to create a file. I define directories up above this code, and I know that's working fine. For some reason it doesn't create the file.

Comment: @user3799576 Comments have lousy formatting.  To make it more clear, maybe you could put that info as a new section at the end of your question.

Comment: I was wondering how I would create a new file in shell. I'm creating a new file by saying file="mytext", but for some reason it doesn't create it, and when I try to get its size from R, it says NA. Perhaps my syntax for creating a file is incorrect..

Comment: `file="mytext"` will not create a disk file.  It creates a shell variable called `file`.